# Runtime path to data file in external repo

Tags: bazel

Let's say I have following two Bazel repos ([git repo](https://github.com/lewistg/bazel-external-data-file-demo)):

```
repos
├── data
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── external-data.txt
│   └── WORKSPACE
└── foo
    ├── BUILD.bazel
    ├── foo.py
    ├── local-data.txt
    └── WORKSPACE
```

I am trying to figure out how the `foo.py` script from the `foo` repository can access `external-data.txt` from the `data` repository at runtime.

So far I have it set up so that the `data` repository defines a public file group for `external-data.txt`:

```
# data/BUILD.bazel

filegroup(
    name = "data",
    srcs = ["external-data.txt"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And the `foo` repository declares the `data` repository as a dependency...

```
# foo/WORKSPACE

local_repository(
    name = "data",
    path = "../data",
)
```

...and then references the file-group as data to be used during runtime for `foo.py`:

```
# foo/BUILD.bazel

py_binary(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.py"],
    data = [
        "local-data.txt",
        "@data//:data"
    ]
)
```

But, again, I am not sure which path I should use to access `external-data.txt` at runtime:

```
# foo/foo.py

import os

def dump_file(file_path):
    print(file_path + ":")
    with open(file_path) as file:
        print(file.read())

def main():
    data_files = [
        'local-data.txt', # No problems here
        # What path should I use to access @data//:external-data.txt?
    ]
    for file in data_files:
        dump_file(file)

    print("cwd: " + os.getcwd())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For context, I am using Bazel version 4.1.0 with the `--nolegacy_external_runfiles` flag:

```
bazel run //:foo --nolegacy_external_runfiles --sandbox_debug
```

The output from that command is the following:

```
local-data.txt:
foo
bar
baz

cwd: /home/$USER/.cache/bazel/_bazel_$USER/2da14ac18a4c150d41626b6c1957d2ad/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/foo.runfiles/__main__
```

I am not sure this is relevant, but when I examine the directory `foo.py` outputs as "cwd", I can find the `external-data.txt` file at this relative path:

```
../../../../../../../../../../../experiments/repos/data/external-data.txt
```

Which is the following absolute path:

```
/home/$USER/.cache/bazel/_bazel_$USER/2da14ac18a4c150d41626b6c1957d2ad/execroot/__main__/external/data
```

(Seems like generally the path for external files should be something like `execroot/$WORKSPACE/external/$EXTERNAL_WORKSPACE`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[runfiles.py](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/python/runfiles/runfiles.py) takes care of locating runfiles. It handles lookups in various situations, including running as a runfile of a runfile which is tricky. It has documentation in a comment at the top.

To use it, add `"@rules_python//python/runfiles"` to the `deps` of `foo`. Then, in `foo.py`:

```py
from rules_python.python.runfiles import runfiles

r = runfiles.Create()
print(r.Rlocation("data/data"))
```